# SWIFT: load dynamic framework with patch

Tags: swift, frameworks, patch

I want a framework to be dynamically loaded. I downloaded the framework and put it in the app document dictionary, but I don't know how to replace the old framework.

```
let frameworkName = "myFirstTest.framework"
var path: URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent(frameworkName, isDirectory: false)
if  FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path.absoluteString) {
    print("exist")
} else {
    print("no exist")
}
```

Comment: You can't download a framework to your app's directory and expect it to work. This is not how frameworks work. Suggest you read the excellent Ray Wenderlich to understand https://www.raywenderlich.com/126365/ios-frameworks-tutorial

Comment: mm, is there any way to hot patch on swift? i saw some game app can push button to download and execute in app, how they do that?

Comment: Not possible in swift land, and highly unlikely to be ok with Apple. Which game are you referring to?

Comment: the game is "星城Online"